# What REST API can i use to record a file or a folder in records management site

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to use Alfresco REST API to manage my files and folders in my own interface. Right now i'm trying to activate the records management module but i didn't find the REST APIs that i can use to do it.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: Did you try reading through https://docs.alfresco.com/rm/concepts/gs-api-overview.html ?

Comment: Are you having troubles using the RM/GS module, or actually activating it? What version of Alfresco are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr I already checked, there's no description for the APIs of RM/GS module

Comment: @Lista i activated it, the graphic interface is working but i want to use the REST API in my own interface

Comment: Did you do as it says there, and download the API explorer and try it on your version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a documentation available other than through the API Explorer. You could browse the Swagger file directly though, but I see no point in doing so.

https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2017/06/27/records-management-community-26a
https://github.com/Alfresco/records-management/blob/master/rm-community/rm-community-rest-api-explorer/src/main/webapp/definitions/gs-core-api.yaml

Depending on the version you are using, you could take advantage of someone else's work too.

https://github.com/Alfresco/gs-api-postman-collection

Answer (score 0):

Once you install AGS module on ACS, the AGS API explorer will be available at the following url.

http://localhost/ags-api-explorer